# bidirectional dependency between web applicaton context and service context

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have 2 spring contexts: "webapplication" context and a "core" context. The context "core" is initialized at server startup and attached to a Singleton class that holds the context. The "webapplication" context is initialized when the webapplication is started.

I want to inject bean dependencies from beans in one context to the other (bidirectional access). The webapplication beans are to be "session" scoped beans.

I'm testing this proof of concept with:  webapp bean --> (that depends on) core bean --> (that depends on another) webapp bean.

At the webapplication context initialization i could inject "core" beans to the "webapplication" beans (a BeanFactory that acceses the singleton do the magic), but can't figure out how to do the inverse; because the Spring ThreadLocal that holds the WebApplicationContext is not yet initialized.

The question is.  Is it what i'm trying to do possible?  If the answer is "yes", how would you do that?

Thank's in advance.

EDIT:

I'd realized i'm doing something wrong. The fact is that i'm trying to inject in the service layer a dependency to a session bean, at the wrong time; that is, at the web initialization time when i have no current user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like an architectural issue, not a technical (and certainly not Spring) one. Your separation between *core* context and *web* context is very good. The former handles business processes while the latter is responsible for representation, maybe some API.

The dependency from *web* (representation, access) to *core* is understandable and required - after all you are building an interface over business routines. This is how [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) works by default, creating separate child (web) application context of core context.

I can hardly imagine a use case for inverted dependency. Why is your business logic depending on web layer? What if you try to migrate your application one that to a different representation technique (desktop, mobile)? Can you justify the reason for this inverted dependency? What do you mean by *session bean*?

Bidirectional dependencies, as well as static singletons holding a class-loader wide reference to application context should indicate that something is wrong with the design.

Comment: My business logic dependes on session data, because i need (example) to access/treat the shooping cart bean (that has session scope) from inside a service bean, before sending some info to backend layer.  Singleton pattern is a common practice in many architectures, and our singleton holds the ApplicationContext (not the classloader). Why you say it's a bad design practice?

Comment: @andresoviedo: thanks for clarification. Isn't your business logic called from web layer? If this is the case, just read shopping cart in web layer and pass it explicitly as argument. About singleton - keeping a reference to `ApplicationContext` in singleton's static field (singletons have class-loader scope, that's what I meant) is just ugly and Spring provides better mechanism for that, e.g. context inheritance (as in mentioned Spring MVC). Not to mention that singleton itself is sometimes called an *anti-pattern*.

Comment: Thank you. Mi business logic is called from the web layer. I've already considered passing the web bean to the service layer as an argument, but i wanted to use injection of scoped session beans to simplify the wiring of components.